# ionic 2: Positioning in ionic card

Tags: user-interface, ionic2

How to add an image in the ion-card which looks like the below image.[image]

Comment: Why did you try?

Comment: I want my UI like that. Any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed after some trails.

html :

```
<div id = "card" class="list_item lists_2 clearfix" >
    <div class="list_left list_image">
       <img src="imgsource.png" class="scale-with-grid" alt="home_app_list_icon_3_blue" width="45" height="45">
    </div>
    <div class="list_right">
       <h4>Tutoring</h4>
         <div class="desc"> 
         some content
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.list_item {
    display: block;

}

.gap {
    height: 3%;
}

.list_item .list_left {
    color: #4e4eaa;
}
.list_item .list_image {
    font-size: 0;
}
.list_item .list_left {
    margin-top: 5%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-size: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}

.clearfix {
    zoom: 1;
}

img.scale-with-grid, #Content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.list_right {
    padding: 5px 0 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```